# Semi static/dynamic page

Tags: php, html, dynamic, static, seo

I'm building a real estate website, and I want to have a page for every building in my database, so that I can find these in Google. I was wondering if I should create a static page for each of these, or if there's another way I can find them in Google.

**EDIT:**

I was rather wondering how I should structure these semi static/dynamic pages. I want to have a fixed title and description for the google results, but the photos and other info can be filled in via database info. Does this seem reasonable or am I overseeing things, or can this be done more efficiently?

Really, I'm just saying I want u fixed URL, title and meta description for google. I want the rest to be handled dynamically.

Comment: Google doesn't know the difference between "static" and "dynamic" pages. Just like your web browser, it requests a URL, and gets some content. Beyond that general hint, this question is much too broad for this site. Check the tips in the [help].

Comment: I was rather wondering how I should structure these semi static/dynamic pages. I want to have a fixed title and description for the google results, but the photos and other info can be filled in via database info.

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're asking. You can create whatever pages you like with your data, there's no one right way to structure a page.

Comment: Really, I'm just saying I want u fixed URL, title and meta description for google. I want the rest to be handled dynamically.

Comment: I understand what you want the pages to do (in broad terms). I don't understand what answer you expect to get to this question.

Comment: I was wondering if there isn't a more efficient way than creating static pages, if the content will be handled dynamically anyway. Because otherwise I'd have the same page over a thousand times, but with a different title, which seems pretty useless to me...

Comment: Well, you can just store the list of titles somewhere, e.g. in your database, and build a PHP page which takes an ID and displays appropriate content. Again, there's nothing really "static" or "dynamic" here, just a choice of where you store this data/content.

Comment: Not exactly, cause I want to be able to find all these pages in Google

Comment: See first comment. Google doesn't care how you make the pages. Do you think Stack Overflow creates a static file for each question? No, it just renders the right content based on the URL you visit (or Google crawls).

Comment: how does that happen? because I'm pretty sure they have a file for each question? how would that otherwise work?

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I think you've misunderstood the relationship between files and URLs. When you, or Google, requests a URL, the web server can look at that URL and do whatever it likes with it. Whatever it returns is what shows in your browser, or in the Google search results.

The most obvious way for a web server to respond is to map the URL directly to a path on disk, and return the contents of that file, but that would mean no dynamic content ever appeared. The next obvious step is to run the program at that location, rather than serving its content, but that's still very limiting. Instead, the principle behind most modern websites is that the URL determines both a program to run, and parameters for that program.

So, in your case, the URL `/property.php?id=42` might run the script `property.php`, which would look at the `id` parameter, and fetch the necessary content for property 42 - including the title, meta tags, pictures, etc - from wherever you have stored them in the database. With some extra server configuration, you can make `/property/42-great-three-bed-apartment` an alias for that same URL (note the 42 is still there, so we still have enough to look it up in the database).

This is basically how all modern websites work, including this one right here.

Comment: Does that mean I can link non-existing URL's to Google?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-existing"? A URL "exists" as long as the web server responds with something when you request it. Think of it like a question and answer - you wouldn't say a question is "non-existent", you'd just say there wasn't a sensible answer. A URL is a question, your code decides how to answer. And Google is asking *exactly the same question* as a user reading that page. If you make an index that users can click on links in, Google's robots will click those links as well.

Comment: I'm really just looking for a way to display a fixed URL with dynamic information to display in Google Search results... Still I haven't had an answer explaining how to do just that...

Comment: I'm afraid I just don't know what else to tell you. Maybe if you start simple, it will begin to make more sense: create a script called `property.php` containing `echo $_GET['id'];` in it, and see how many different URLs with different content you can make beginning with `/property.php?id=`. That's really all there is to it, you don't need to "create" anything other than that one script, the rest is just choosing data based on the ID.

Comment: To be clear, the title, meta tags, etc, can all just be stored in your database somewhere. They're not "static", because you want them to be different for each property, so you want to look them up based on the ID along with everything else. And the URLs with ?id= in them are ugly, but they're just as "real" as any other URL; once you have them working, you can learn about "URL rewriting" to make your web server answer to prettier URLs with the same content. But *don't worry about that yet*, take things one step at a time.